# Emulator showing momentarily on Android Studio on Mac

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I am using Android Studio on Mac Mojave 10.14.4

During development one of the emulators stopped responding because of which I had to force close using the Activity Monitor. Ever since then whenever I click on run app in Android Studio I see the zombie emulator appearing momentarily and then disappearing and this entire cycle keeps on repeating.

Attaching Gif for the same. When I keep 2 emulators open this stops but the moment I close one emulator it starts this behaviour again.

I am unable to push the build to any device.

I have already tried adb kill-server & adb start-server and deleted all emulators, recreated them as well. Didn't help. Tried 2 different versions of Android Studio as well but didn't help

Also when no emulators exist then also this shows up.

Any pointers will be appreciated !

[image]

Comment: I don't know particularly of Mac Mojave. But, several virtual machines don't run properly on it. You should run your app via USB to an android device. It will show up in your `Connected Devices`. You'll have to set your android device to developer mode and it will automatically connect with the adb and show logs on your logcat. Here's more: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device